# weird pluperfect subjunctive in Eutropius

Tags: conjunctive, tenses

In *Rōma Æterna*, p. 239, in a passage from Eutropius, book 28, comes the paragraph:

> P. Scīpiō in Hispāniā cum Poenīs dēbellāvit quārtō decimō annō eius bellī; et ā Tarracōne in Āfricam ad Syphācem, rēgem Massȳlōrum, trānsvectus, foedus cum eō iūnxit. Et amīcitiā factā cum Masinissā, rēge Numidārum (quī illī auxilium 'sī in Āfricam **trāiēcisset**' pollicēbātur), Rōmam reversus cōnsulque creātus.

I'd expect *trāiceret* or *trāiectūrus esset*. Why the pluperfect subjunctive here?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is a quirk of conditions in indirect statement: a perfect subjunctive in the protasis of a future less vivid condition turns to pluperfect subjunctive when in indirect statement. For examples see [Allen and Greenough 589](http://dcc.dickinson.edu/allen-greenough/Chapters/Chapter-589.html), 2.a.3.

What's a little unusual about this example is that *pollicebatur* isn't introducing a full indirect statement, but just takes an object *auxilium*. However, the 'if' clause is still behaving as if it's part of a complete condition (e.g. *pollicebatur se auxilium laturum esse si...*).

Comment: Thank you so much! I've been trying to figure this one out for hours. . . .